# What does 'underwriting' mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context

In the following excerpt, how should I interpret *underwriting*, is the word synonymous with *justifying*? If so why is that word used outside of am insurance context?

> Given to mystical preoccupations, this android proposed the group escape attempt, **underwriting** it ideologically with a pretentious fiction as to the sacredness of so-called android “life.”

Comment: Note that, literally and metaphorically, "underwrite" is often used to mean "provide money in support of".

Comment: Do not interpret the ability to deduce sense from flowery language for ... underwriting that style.

Comment: Sounds like an “answer” on Jeopardy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sense is figurative:

***[Underwrite](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/underwrite)***:

> to support or concur with (a decision, statement, etc) by or as if by signature.

(Collins Dictionary)